# Datatype gets changed when exporting a dataframe to csv in r

Tags: r, dataframe, unit-testing, testthat

I'm write a testscript to check to whether the data is being read. The data is read as a dataframe. I'm writing this list to a csv to read it again as a csv file. But after writing to a csv file the datatypes got changed. How do I solve this issue?

```
test_that(desc = "Test for 'ReadData' Condition 1",
          code = {
            identifier = "Test"
            wdPath = file.path(getwd(),"Data/xyz", identifier)
            Actual_Output = ReadData(wdPath)
            Expected_Output = read.csv("./UnitTest/Data/Expected_baseData.csv",
                                       header = TRUE)
            expect_equal(Actual_Output, Expected_Output)
          })
```

ReadData is a function to read the data and it returns a dataframe. Now when I export it to csvband read it back all the datatypes gets changed. The ReadData function is as follows:

```
ReadData = function(wdPath) {
  
  Data = fread(file = list.files(file.path(wdPath, "Olt"), full.names = TRUE) %>% 
                     as.data.frame(.) %>% 
                     filter(stri_detect(str = ., fixed = ".csv")) %>% 
                     unlist(.) %>% 
                     as.character(.),
                   data.table = FALSE,
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                   encoding = "UTF-8",
                   colClasses = "character") %>% 
    mutate(a = as.numeric(a),
           dc = as.numeric(dc),
           SN = as.numeric(SN))
  
  return(Data)
}
```

This is the error

```
Error: `Actual_Output` not equal to `Expected_Output`.
Component “b”: Modes: character, numeric
Component “b”: target is character, current is numeric
Component “x”: Modes: character, numeric
Component “x”: Attributes: < target is NULL, current is list >
Component “x”: target is character, current is factor
Component “a”: Modes: character, numeric
Component “a”: Attributes: < target is NULL, current is list >
Component “a”: target is character, current is factor
Component “a”: Modes: character, numeric
```

This is the error I get; when I check the datatypes, there is a datatype mismatch between expected output and the actual output.

The input is as follows:

```
dput(Data)
structure(list(b = c("143", "123"), x = c("2018/03", "2018/07"), No = c("105", "106"), 
    j = c("1", "2"), a = c(120, 164), SN = c(1, 1)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It's unclear how much anyone could help without knowledge of (1) the `ReadData()` function and (2) the content of the files being read (and likely how they were created in the first place)

Comment: @duckmayr, I will add the ReadData function as well as a sample data

Comment: So in `ReadData()`, you're reading **everything** in as character, then only converting _some_ of them to numeric. `read.csv()` is going to convert _all_ of those columns that are just numbers to numeric. That looks to be a fair portion of your problem (though it might not fix everything)